# MySQL: concatenate columns of tables one-to-many

Tags: mysql, concatenation

I have 2 tables (`person` + `person_products`)

where each person has at least 1 product.

Sample person table:

```
person_id | name
------------------
1         | Alice
2         | Peter
3         | James
```

Sample person_products table:

```
id | person_id | description | price
------------------------------------
1  | 1         | iphone 5    | 100
2  | 1         | iphone 6    | 200
3  | 1         | samsung     | 300
4  | 2         | tv          | 110
5  | 3         | oven        | 250
6  | 3         | microwave   | 260
```

I want to do the following:

```
SELECT p.person_id, 
some_concat_product_descriptions, 
some_concat_product_prices
FROM person p
LEFT JOIN person_products p on p.person_id = pp.person_id
```

Expected result:

```
person_id | concat_product_descriptions | concat_product_prices
---------------------------------------------------------------
1         | iphone 5, iphone 6, samsung | 100, 200, 300
2         | tv                          | 110
3         | oven, microwave             | 250, 260
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [group_concat](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat)

```
SELECT p.person_id, 
       group_concat(pp.description order by pp.description) as concat_product_descriptions,
       group_concat(pp.price order by pp.description) as concat_product_prices
FROM person p
LEFT JOIN person_products pp on p.person_id = pp.person_id
GROUP BY p.person_id
```

Answer (score -1):

Use [group_concat aggregation function](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-functions.html). A join is is not needed at all.

```
select 
  person_id,
  group_concat(description) separator ', ' as concat_product_descriptions,
  group_concat(price) separator ', ' as concat_product_prices
group by 
  person_id
```